# C++ logical conditions inside if statements

Tags: c++, if-statement, logical-operators

```
int a = 2;

if((a = a-3 && --a ) || a--) 
    cout<<a<<endl;
```

The doubt I have is, ( a = a-3 && --a) would make a = -1 because a-3 = -1. What does the left side evaluate to? And if the compiler does go to the right side of OR does it take the original value of a (i.e. 2) or the modified value of a from the left side
How is the output for this code 1? What is happening under the hood? Is it like only one side of the if statement is executed?

Comment: What do you expect that `a-3 && --a` will evaluate to? (Not sure if the issue is operator precedence or short-circuiting.)

Comment: Time to start staring at the old operator-precedence table ( https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence )... and there's a special place in hell for anyone who writes code like this in a real program :)

Comment: Just to spell it out, `a = a-3 && --a` is, with extra brackets to highlight the order of precedence, `a = ((a-3) && --a)`

Comment: you are mixing operator precedence understanding and boolean [Short-circuit_evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation): you are not helping yourself learning. for `&&` and `||` operators: in c++ the right operand is evaluated only if the left one "is not enough" to get the result: if the left side of the  `||` (or)  is true, the result will be true anyway and the right part, by design, is not evaluated

Comment: Consider the perspective of someone who knows what is going on, the sort of person you might want to answer your question. This person might look at your code and see that *obviously* the output should be `1`, no explanation needed. That leaves us at a non-productive standoff. You say that the output should not be `1`, while the other person says it should. Not productive. It would help if one of the people explained the evaluation. I suggest you take on that role, to set a good example for whomever answers. What did you expect the output to be, and why?

Comment: So the people who misunderstood the point of this question - this is purely to understand how c++ works and no, this is not used in a real application. The doubt I had is, ( a = a-3 && --a) would make a = -1 because a-3 = -1. What does the left side evaluate to? And if the compiler does go to the right side of OR does it take the original value of a (i.e. 2) or the modified value of a from the left side.

Comment: @Karan *"So the people who misunderstood the point of this question"* -- I would take the number of people who misunderstood as a sign that the question is not written well. It should be edited to be clearer about the point of the problem. Add your expectations -- what you put in your comment would be a good start, but go into more details, listing each step you expected the evaluation to take. *Also, it might help your question's quality if you could simplify the expression. Do you need both the `&&` and the `||` to get a result different than you expect?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ( a = a-3 && --a) would make a = -1 because a-3 = -1.

You've missed the order of operations here, where `&&` is evaluated before assignment. (Assignment is almost the last thing evaluated, which makes sense when it is used outside conditionals.) It is true that `a-3` is `-1`, but that value is not assigned to `a`. Rather, that is the left side of `&&`, and it evaluates to `true` since it is used in a boolean context. Next the right side of `&&` is evaluated, reducing `a` to `1` and evaluating to `1`. Like the left side, this is converted to a boolean (`true`), causing the expression `a-3 && --a` to evaluate to `true`.

So your assignment boils down to `a = true`, with `true` converting to `1` since `a` is an `int`.

> What does the left side evaluate to?

I presume you mean the left side of `&&`? That expression (`a-3`) evaluates to `true` as a boolean.

> And if the compiler does go to the right side of OR [...]

It does not, because `||` short circuits for boolean values. (User-defined `operator||` does not short-circuit, though.) The left side evaluates to `1` (the value assigned to `a`), which converts to `true` in a boolean context. When the left side of `||` evaluates to `true`, the right side is not evaluated.

> How is the output for this code 1?

That is what `true` converted to when you assigned it to `a`.

> What is happening under the hood?

```
(a =  a-3 &&  --a ) || a--
(a =  2-3 &&  --a ) || a--
(a =   -1 &&  --a ) || a--
(a = true &&  --a ) || a--
(a = true &&   1  ) || a--
(a = true && true ) || a--
(a =     true     ) || a--
(a =       1      ) || a--
(        1        ) || a--
(      true       ) || a--
           true
```

> Is it like only one side of the if statement is executed?

I don't understand what a "side" of an `if` statement would be. Possibly you meant "conditional" instead of "statement"? Regardless, the above probably answered what you meant to ask.

To get the result you seem to have been expecting, add parentheses to override the usual [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence):

```
if(( (a = a-3) && --a ) || a--)
//   ^       ^
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation! Very well written. The step-by-step walkthrough cleared the doubt.

Answer (score -2):

it first check this :

```
a-3 && --a
```

`a-3` is `-1` and is not equal zero so result is (`true`)

`--a` is not zero and result is 1 (`true`)
so `a=true` and `true` is `1`
so `a=1;`

the compiler is not check second part and goes to next line

so it prints `1` for output